# Detect when ajax finishes loading all images with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

What happens is this. Try this example:

**index.html**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("ready", function(){
        $(document).load("h.html", function(d){
            document.write(d);
            alert("Done!");
        })
    })
</script>
```

And other file: **h.html**

```
<img src="http://www.noao.edu/noao/staff/kolsen/images/M31.jpg" width="600"/>
```

I want to achieve is to load images using jquery ajax and ... and detect when all the images have fully loaded asynchronously. SI fixing, loading the petition shows a warning message, but the image is still loading. I want to detect when it's fully charged. How do I do?

Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at this: https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages Perhaps it's exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Is there a reason to not load the images directly?

Answer (score 1):

Try the ImagesLoaded plugin. It comes in handy for many image issues.

https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded

```
imagesLoaded( '#container', function() {...});
```